# Groovy skips JsonNode objects on checking for null even if they not null

Tags: groovy

Why Groovy skips this if statement?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonNode jsonNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
    if (jsonNode) {
        println 'It works' //doesn't print it
    }
}
```

Explicit checking for null works well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonNode jsonNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
    if (jsonNode != null) {
        println 'It works' //works well
    }
}
```

Imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

Also if I use breakpoints in Intellij it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Groovy Object#asBoolean.
By default it returns false if object is null.

[asBoolean()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#asBoolean())

> Coerce an object instance to a boolean value. An object is coerced to
>   true if it's not null, to false if it is null.

Groovy tries to cast object to boolean with asBoolean() when there is such check.
This example shows that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsBoolFalse asBoolFalse = new AsBoolFalse()
    if (asBoolFalse) {
        println 'AsBoolFalse doesn\'t work' //doesn't print it
    }

    AsBoolTrue asBoolTrue = new AsBoolTrue()
    if (asBoolTrue) {
        println 'AsBoolTrue works' //works well
    }
}

static class AsBoolFalse {
    public boolean asBoolean() {
        return false
    }
}

static class AsBoolTrue {
    public boolean asBoolean() {
        return true
    }
}
```

JsonNode overrides asBoolean() to return false, so we need explicit check for null.

Comment: I don't get it. You both asked and answered the question 24 min ago? Nice.

Comment: I found an answer during I was writing this question. So I've decided not to skip this question and go on with the answer. Maybe it will be useful for somebody. It wasn't clear for me for two days why I got such behavior.

Comment: Yes, it has helped a lot! Described behaviour is still valid.